# A question about 3-D Rotations in a Coordinate Plane?

Tags: matrices, rotations

I was reading the following article about how to represent a $3$-D rotation in coordinates: [link](http://motion.pratt.duke.edu/RoboticSystems/3DRotations.html)

I saw that in order to do a rotation around the Z-axis, the rotation matrix is: $$\begin{equation}R_Z(\theta) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta  & -\sin \theta   & 0 \\
\sin\theta  & \cos \theta   & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}$$

In order to do a rotation around the X-axis, the rotation matrix is: $$\begin{equation}R_X(\theta) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta  & -\sin \theta  \\
0 & \sin\theta  & \cos \theta   
\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}$$

In order to do a rotation matrix around the Y-axis, the rotation matrix is: $$\begin{equation}R_Y(\theta) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta   
\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}$$

Let's say I wanted to rotate some point, $(x, y, z)$, $\alpha^{\circ}$ about the Z-axis, $\beta^{\circ}$ around the X-axis, and $\gamma^{\circ}$ around the $Y$-axis.

Then, could I represent the coordinates as: $$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha   & 0 \\
\sin\alpha  & \cos \alpha   & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \beta  & -\sin \beta  \\
0 & \sin\beta  & \cos \beta   
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \gamma & 0 & \sin\gamma \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin \gamma & 0 & \cos \gamma   
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x \\
y \\
z \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}?
$$

Is there some simpler way to do it so that I don't have to work with all of these matrices? Does anyone know of a general form that'll move everything into one matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) turns an axis and angle into a single rotation matrix, which in its most general form is an orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$. Alternatively, use quaternions.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Is there some way to generalize to, let's say n dimensions? For example, assume I had coordinates $(x_1, x_2 \cdots x_n)$ and rotations of $\theta_1, \theta_2 \cdots \theta_n$. Is there some general way to represent that?

Comment: @sfs2007 For higher dimensions, there's no way that's really much beter than what you saw for the 3D case: successive rotations about different axes (Euler angles).

Comment: would a quaternion be usable for n dimensions? From the preliminary research I did about quaternions vs Euler angles, it said that quaternions are generally easier to work with when doing rotations...

Comment: @sfs2007 No. Quaternions are only available for 3D rotations, which is the most common case in the real world anyway.

Comment: ok thanks... When I learned more about quaternions, they talked about how I need to figure out the axis of rotation. Is it true that any rotation can be written as a combination of rotations along the x, y, z axes?

Comment: @sfs2007 Yes, that is true.